# Customizing make.names function in R?

Tags: r, identifier, illegal-characters

I am automating a R code for which I have to use `make.names` function. Default behavior of `make.names` function is fine with me but when my table name contains a "-", I want the table name to be different.

For example, current behavior :

```
  > make.names("iris-ir")
    [1] "iris.ir"
```

But I want it to modify only in the case when I have "-" present in table name:

```
    > make.names("iris-ir")
    [1] "iris_ir"
```

How can I achieve this? EDIT: using only builtin packages.

Comment: `gsub`. Or `janitor::clean_names`.

Comment: Can you suggest me full code her with gsub here

Comment: `names(df) <- gsub('-', '_', names(df))`

Answer (score 3):

Use the following function:

```
library(dplyr)
make_names<-function(name)
  {
    name <- as.character(name)
    if(contains("-", vars = name))
       sub("-", "_", name)
  }
```

This should do what you want.
Sorry, I forgot to mention that the `contains` function is in the `dplyr` package.

**Without dplyr**

```
make_names<-function(name)
  {
    name <- as.character(name)
    if(grepl("-", name, fixed = T))
       sub("-", "_", name)
    else
       name
  }
```

Comment: `contains` is not a base R function afaik. When using packages, you should make that clear by loading them.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use dplyr package. I am automating some code of open source which can only use core packages

Comment: @HiveRLearner: then you need to state that requirement in your question